# How to Session checking in OnClientUploadStarted="uploadStarted" function using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

Lets say someone logged in and leave the application as an idle and again using it. In the mean time the session was time-out. So, in this position session should be give null, but still it is displaying the assigned value in the JavaScript where as code behind showing null value.
Now what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a scenario where the user does not reload the page after the session expires, and hence the cookie value (assuming your session is cookie-based) is not removed/updated to reflect the new state of the session.

If you would like to update this in real time via your client-side code, you will have to check with the server by making a request on a set interval. The server-side handler should simply respond with the state of the session, and the client-side code should update whatever variables/cookies necessary to maintain state in your app.

This will introduce extra requests for users that are NOT idle, so then you would need some way to detect if a client is actually idle before triggering the request loop. Overall, you will need to evaluate if this "feature" is worth the extra requests and complexity that will be introduced.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But how to do it? Is there any JavaScript code,if so please provide.